# Comprobar conexión del socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, server

Quería saber si existe alguna manera para comprobar, en el **server socket**, si el **cliente** está conectado, con un `if` por ejemplo.

Partiendo del siguiente código, lo que se me ha ocurrido es el `if clientConnection.close is True` para que cuando el cliente se desconecte del socket, se cumpla la condición y el server (con el `break`) vuelva a aceptar una petición.

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((local, port))
server.listen(1)
print("Server started")

while True: 
    print ("WAITING FOR CLIENT...")               
    clientConnection,clientAddress = server.accept()
    print ("CONNECTED CLIENT: ", clientAddress)

    while True:  
        recv = clientConnection.recv(4096)

        if clientConnection.close is True:
            break
```

Comment: ¿Lo probaste? ¿Qué resultado te dio?

Comment: Sí, lo he probado, al cerrar la conexión del cliente, en el servidor me da el siguiente error: `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando el cliente cierra la conexión, `recv` retorna `b''`.

Código:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4002))
server.listen(1)
print("Server started")

while True:
    print ("WAITING FOR CLIENT...")
    clientConnection,clientAddress = server.accept()
    print ("CONNECTED CLIENT: ", clientAddress)

    while True:
        recv = clientConnection.recv(4096)
        if recv != b'':
            print(recv)
        else:
            clientConnection.close()
            break
```

produce:

```
Server started
WAITING FOR CLIENT...
CONNECTED CLIENT:  ('127.0.0.1', 58172)
b'hola\n'
b'chao\n'
WAITING FOR CLIENT...
```

cuando el cliente hace:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ nc 127.0.0.1 4002
hola
chao
^C
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$
```

Comment: Cuando el cliente cierra la comunicación el server continua cerrándose. Tampoco recibo mas de un mensaje del cliente.

Comment: @andyio Como puedes ver en el ejemplo, después de que el cliente cierra la conexión con CTRL-C, el servidor vuelve a quedar a la espera, imprimiendo por segunda vez "WAITING ..". Comprobe el código nuevamente y opera correctamente con múltiples conexiones en serie (una a la vez).